# App crash on viewDidDisappear

Tags: ios, swift, crash

There is a very strange crash that occurs only on 5, 5s and SE models with iOS 10.2. Firebase says that 100% of crashes happened in background.

I got able to exactly reproduce the stack of crash (but not the crash itself on the simulator) and only figured out that it happens when the user quit an app. Seems like no other code of viewDidDisappear get called on real crash, because the stack changes in this case.

Actually, the line that mentioned in crash report goes straight after
 super.viewDidDisappear(animated) and it is blank…

```
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        self.keyboardAvoiding.endAvoiding()
    }
```

KeyboardAvoiding

```
 func endAvoiding()
{
    self.avoiding = false

    // Update view frame
    updateConstraint(nil)
}


   private func updateConstraint(_ keyboardFrame: CGRect?, animationDuration: TimeInterval? = 0.0)
    {
        // Disable animation
        let state = UIView.areAnimationsEnabled
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)

        // Force to recalculate view frame if needed (without animation)
        self.view.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()

        // Restore previous animation state
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(state)

        if let keyboardFrame = keyboardFrame
        {
            // Decrease view frame
            self.constraint.constant = keyboardFrame.height
        }
        else {
            // Reset bottom constraint to initial value
            self.constraint.constant = self.initialConstraintConstant
        }

        // Layout superview
        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration ?? 0.0, animations: {
            self.view.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
            if let keyboardAvoidingScrollView = self.view.firstViewOfClass(TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.self)
            {
                // Scroll to active text field if scroll view frame changed
                keyboardAvoidingScrollView.scrollToActiveTextField()
            }
        })

    }
```

Here is a crash report:

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,2
Code Type:       ARM-64
Parent Process:  ??? [1]

OS Version:      iPhone OS 10.2 (14C92)

Exception Type:  SIGTRAP
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x100255178
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
Selector name found in current argument registers: release

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   _______                              0x0000000100255178 _______.PhoneNumberController.viewDidDisappear(Swift.Bool) -> () (PhoneNumberController.swift:97)
1   _______                              0x00000001002551a4 @objc _______.PhoneNumberController.viewDidDisappear(Swift.Bool) -> () (PhoneNumberController.swift:0)
2   UIKit                                0x000000018e7026f4 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 524
3   UIKit                                0x000000018e7765b4 -[UIViewController __viewDidDisappear:] + 140
4   UIKit                                0x000000018e7c02e0 -[UINavigationController viewDidDisappear:] + 228
5   UIKit                                0x000000018e7026f4 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 524
6   UIKit                                0x000000018e7765b4 -[UIViewController __viewDidDisappear:] + 140
7   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001887ceb10 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 16
8   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001887ce214 _CFXRegistrationPost + 396
9   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001887cdf90 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 56
10  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018883db8c -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1500
11  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018870fe64 _CFXNotificationPost + 372
12  Foundation                           0x0000000189244e0c -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64
13  UIKit                                0x000000018e9785d8 __102-[UIApplication _handleApplicationDeactivationWithScene:shouldForceExit:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.2100 + 288
14  UIKit                                0x000000018e97bfdc _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 288
15  UIKit                                0x000000018e96dd50 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 556
16  UIKit                                0x000000018e6dd0b4 _afterCACommitHandler + 164
17  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001887e20c0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
18  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001887dfcf0 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
19  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001887e0180 __CFRunLoopRun + 1020
20  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018870e2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 440
21  GraphicsServices                     0x000000018a1c2198 GSEventRunModal + 176
22  UIKit                                0x000000018e7557fc -[UIApplication _run] + 680
23  UIKit                                0x000000018e750534 UIApplicationMain + 204
24  _______                              0x00000001000e3188 main (AppDelegate.swift:25)
25  ???                                  0x00000001876f15b8 0x0 + 0
```

Comment: add respective code.

Comment: have you registered any notification observer in the viewcontroller?

Comment: nope. there are no any notification observers… but i got ivar of type KeyboardAvoiding that has keyboard observers. it correctly removes observers if controller calls deinit.

Comment: Its better if you use IQKeyboardManager instead this library "TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView", you do not to need to manage scrolltoactivenexttextfield. It automatically manages if you make particular textfield/textview become first responder .

Comment: it's not up to me